# How to programatically fast forward video on a website

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, webapi, browser-extension

I'm considering writting a browser plugin (firefox or chrome), that will trigger a fast forward or skip on an embedded video player on a website. Its not youtube, but a custom video player component. No idea what it is.

Using developer tools, I can see that the video has a skip 10s button, that has a specific Div ID. Similar to youtube, it also have one of thoes progress bars, that you can click on to skip to different parts of the video.

How would I go about creating an action on this video, to fast forward or skip? Is there some sort of API in the browser I can use, to perorm these sorts of actions?

Thanks,

Comment: "How would I go about creating an action on this video" ... What have you tried?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question requires code.

Comment: You mean setting the [playback rate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playbackRate) and [current time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)?